# Error while converting Dataframe to Geodataframe

Tags: shapefile, convert, geodataframe

I am trying to convert a table to a shapefile. To do that, I am storing that table in a dataframe and then I am trying to convert that dataframe to geodataframe using GeoPandas. But I am getting an error:

> `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

I am using the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point

city_dict=dict()
city_dict={"lat":Lat_list,"long":long_list,"city":city_list,"population":population_list,"area":area_list}
print(city_dict)

df=pd.DataFrame(city_dict)

crs_dict = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

geometry_list=list()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    city_name=row['city']
    lat=row['lat']
    long=row['long'] 
    point=Point(float(long),float(lat))
    print (point)
    geometry_list.append(point)

df['geometry']=geometry_list
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs_dict, geometry='geometry')
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code* with pandas=0.24.1 and geopandas=0.4.0, and it ran without error.

For what it's worth, the geopandas documentation offers example code for [Creating a GeoDataFrame from a DataFrame with coordinates](https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html), and it is not necessary to use iterrows on the DataFrame to build the geometries point by point, nor is it necessary to add the geometry column to the DataFrame first. Arguably, this should be avoided, so that you can distinguish between DataFrame that don't have geometries and GeoDataFrames that do.

The example code from the documentation. The code is slightly modified to follow your conventions:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

city_dict = {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]}
df = pd.DataFrame(city_dict)
crs_dict = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs_dict, 
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)
    )
```

If you are using geopandas<0.5.0, `points_from_xy` won't be available to you, in which case you can use a list compehension with the shapely Point constructor:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs_dict, 
    geometry=[Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)]
    )
```

---

* I didn't test your exact code because you didn't supply city data. I used the example dict given above from the geopandas documentation.

Comment: I am using pandas 0.25.1, and geopandas 0.6.2. I tried your code and getting the same error.

Comment: Can you add your city data to the code sample?